# Alternatives App Stores (iOS) : Security risks

Tags: ios, security

Alternatives App Stores (iOS) : Security risks

Hi, I recently downloaded an iOS app from an unofficial store (GBA4iOS, from Builds.io website).

Before installing any application, you have to install the developper profile on your device.

Is there any security risks by using those apps? 
I mean, can they bypass Apple restrictions? Access to Photos, Camera, GPS... without user authorization.

Comment: I would support asking the profile question as a stand alone one. Feel free to link it here in comments if it doesn't get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Trust

If you do not trust the provider or developer of the apps being installed, you should not install their software.

### Avoiding the App Store, Why?

If the app or the developer has not been accepted into the official Apple App Store, then you need to consider why.

- Is the developer or app unable to function within [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) – if so, what functionality went beyond the guidelines and why might Apple restrict it?
- Has Apple rejected the app as a risk to users? If so, what is the app doing that Apple dislikes?
- Is the app also available on the official App Store? Why is a copy available outside the store? Are you depriving the developer of income or customers? Might the non-App Store edition be tampered with?
- Does the developer have a political reason not to distribute their app via Apple; do you understand and agree with this position?

### Technical Distractions

There are technical arguments to [avoid installing custom](https://www.howtogeek.com/176195/why-configuration-profiles-can-be-as-dangerous-as-malware-on-iphones-and-ipads/) [or developer profiles](https://www.skycure.com/blog/malicious-profiles-the-sleeping-giant-of-ios-security/), but those arguments shift over time. The questions above are more important to focus on.

How comfortable do *you* feel about trusting your device with the non-Apple provider and associated developers?

Comment: Avoiding the App Store : In the case of Builds.io, they provide emulators, tweaked apps (YouTube, Snapchat, Spotify...), streaming apps... That's why they don't function within Apple guidelines

Comment: Personal feeling : I also use the YouTube tweak because it's more confortable than the official app (main reason : background play). But for me, security is more important. That's why I asked the question